# HTMLScriptElement is not a function in IOS webview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webview

```js
const loadJs = (path, fn, target) => {
  let elem = document.createElement('script'), loaded;
  elem.onload = elem.onerror = elem.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if ((elem.readyState && !(/^c|loade/.test(elem.readyState))) || loaded) {
      return;
    }
    elem.onload = elem.onreadystatechange = null;
    loaded = 1;
    fn();
  };
  elem.async = 1;
  elem.src = path;
  target.appendChild(elem);
};
```

HTMLScriptElement is not a function in IOS webview,
It looks like that 'appendChild' has compatibility

[image]